# How to wrap jQuery (default) handsontable inside directive AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, handsontable

Here I have a handsontable working in a non-AngularJS app, and I'm working on a new version of the software that make use of AngularJS extensively (SPA).

I would know: is there a way to wrap the existing handsontable implementation inside an AngularJS directive without rewriting everything?

Thank you in advance!

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    colHeaders: configTable.columnsHeader,
    columns: configTable.columnsConfig,
    colWidths: configTable.colWidths,
    rowHeight: 5,
    data: configTable.data,
    minSpareRows: 0,
    rowHeaders: false,
    contextMenu: false,
    currentRowClassName: 'row_selected',
    height: parentWindowHeight,
    width: parentWindowWidth,
    multiSelect: false,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    autoWrapCol: true,
    fillHandle: false,
    afterOnCellMouseOver: function (event, coords, cell) {
        // Long Implementation...
    },
    afterOnCellMouseDown: function (r, p, r2, p2) { //(r: Number, p: Number, r2: Number, p2: Number)
        // Long Implementation...
    },
    beforeKeyDown: function (event) { // event: Object
    },
    beforeChange: function (changes, source) { //(changes: Array, source: String)
        // Long Implementation...
    },
    afterChange: function (changes, source) { // (changes: Array, source: String)
        // Long Implementation...
    },
    beforeValidate: function (value, row, prop, source) { // value: Mixed, row: Number, prop: String, source: String
        valorMaximo = numeral($(hot.getColHeader()[prop]).data('valor')).value();
    },
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};

        var sit = $(this.instance.getData()[row][0])[0];

        if (sit !== undefined) {
            sit = sit.value;

            if (sit != "1" && sit != "+" && sit != "-" && sit != "*") {
                cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                cellProperties.renderer = disabledRowRenderer;
            }
        }

        return cellProperties;
    },
    onSelection: function (r, c, r2, c2) { // readOnly cannot be selected
        var sit = $(this.getData()[r][0])[0];
        var meta = this.getCellMeta(r, c);

        if (sit !== undefined) {
            sit = sit.value;

            if (sit != "1" && sit != "+" && sit != "-" && sit != "*") {
                this.deselectCell();
            }
        }

        if (meta.readOnly) {
            this.deselectCell();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can of course. The simplest way is to create a simple directive where you put all the existing logic inside your link function. You probably need to tweak the code a bit in order to get the right reference to the element you are working with. See:

```
myApp.directive('handsOnTable', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element){
            // Your code here, using the element attribute.
        }
    };
});
```

BUT...since you are switching to AngularJS I highly recommend rewriting your code. It might not be that hard and not that much work at all. It will give you more futureproof code though and you can probably get rid of jQuery (which you should, actually). In your case that would probably mean that most of the options like autoWrapRow and autoWrapCol would become attributes on your directive and methods like beforeValidate will end up in a controller. Something like:

```
myApp.directive('handsOnTable', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
          autoWrapRow: '=',
          autoWrapCol: '='
        },
        controller: function($element){
            var vm = this;

            vm.beforeValidate = beforeValidate;

            function beforeValidate(){
               // Do stuff. You can use the $element to do DOM manupulation
               // but you should keep that to a minimum and try to think the
               // Angular way of doing things.
            }
        },
        controllerAs: 'table',
        bindToController: true
    };
});
```

Hope this helps a bit. Of course it depends a lot on how good you are with Angular.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll think about this. o/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ngHandsontable library which doesn't need jQuery?

https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable?